# Joda time : How to convert String to LocalDate?

Tags: java, jodatime

How to specify the format string to convert the date alone from string. In my case, only the date part is relevant

Constructing it as `DateTime` fails:

```
String dateString = "2009-04-17";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(dateString);
```

with error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2011-04-17" is too short`

Probably because I should use `LocalDate` instead. But, I do not see any formatter for `LocalDate` . What is the best way to convert `String dateString = "2009-04-17";` into `LocalDate` (or something else if that is not the right representation)

thanks...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`LocalDate(Object)`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#LocalDate(java.lang.Object)). It's a bit confusing since it takes a generic `Object`, but the docs indicate that it will use a [`ConverterManager`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/convert/ConverterManager.html) that knows how to handle a `String` if you pass a `String` to the constructor, e.g.

```
LocalDate myDate = new LocalDate("2010-04-28");
```

Comment: It certainly is a potentially confusing Javadoc entry.

Comment: thanks a lot for the pointer... I'm bit confused how to use ConverterManager. How do I pass the string to it? Do I need need to add a partial converter to it? but it says by default it accepts string for partial convert. If you could give an example, it would be great help.. thanks

Comment: Sorry my answer wasn't clear enough, but it looks like you figured it out. I did indeed mean `final LocalDate myDate = new LocalDate("2010-04-28");`

Comment: So does this *always* want the format of the string in 'YYYY-MM-DD' ? or could other platforms require different orders ? (I'm trying to just validate a date string : and for my purposes I always want it in YYYY-MM-DD)

Answer (score 22):

Use the `parse(String)` method.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2009-04-17");
```

Answer (score 10):

There's a somewhat subtle bug-ish issue with using `LocalDate.parse()` or `new LocalDate()`. A code snippet is worth a thousand words. In the following example in the scala repl I wanted to get a Local date in a string format yyyyMMdd. `LocalDate.parse()` is happy to give me an instance of a LocalDate, but it's not the correct one (`new LocalDate()` has the same behavior):

```
scala> org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse("20120202")
res3: org.joda.time.LocalDate = 20120202-01-01
```

I give it Feb 2, 2016 in the format yyyyMMdd and I get back a date of January 1, 20120202. I'm going out on a limb here: I don't think that this is what it should be doing. Joda uses 'yyyy-MM-dd' as the default but implicitly will accept a string with no '-' characters, thinking you want January 1 of that year? That does not seem like a reasonable default behavior to me.

Given this, it seems to me that using a joda date formatter that can't be so easily fooled is a better solution to parsing a string. Moreover, `LocalDate.parse()` should probably throw an exception if the date format is not 'yyyy-MM-dd':

```
scala> val format = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd")
format: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter@56826a75

scala> org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse("20120202", format)
res4: org.joda.time.LocalDate = 2012-02-02
```

this will cause other formats to fail so you don't get this odd buggy behavior:

```
scala> val format = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
format: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter@781aff8b

scala> org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse("20120202", format)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "20120202" is too short
  at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:900)
  at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDate(DateTimeFormatter.java:844)
  at org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:179)
  ... 65 elided
```

which is a much more sane behavior than returning a date in the year 20120202.

Comment: Joda clearly statis in the javadocs:
`It accepts formats described by the following syntax:
       date-element      = std-date-element | ord-date-element | week-date-element
       std-date-element  = yyyy ['-' MM ['-' dd]]
       ord-date-element  = yyyy ['-' DDD]
       week-date-element = xxxx '-W' ww ['-' e]
`. I think this is quite sane behaviour.

Comment: stating in the docs is one thing, giving a big pit 'o failure to fall into is another, methinks

Answer (score 5):

In my case, incoming string may be in one of two formats. So I first try to parse string with more specific format:

```
String s = "2016-02-12";
LocalDateTime ldt;
try {
    ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm"));
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LocalDate.of` with the year, month and day passed as separate arguments:

```
LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(2009, 4, 17);
LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2009, Month.APRIL, 17);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse("2014-07-19");
LocalDate dNow = LocalDate.now();  // Current date
```

Comment: What's the point of this answer? The accepted answer is better, with simpler code, and also gives an explanation.