# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20110328094108069414"

Tags: java, exception

Am trying to convert a String value to long, and am getting : `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20110328094108069414"`

My code :

```
  String buyId  = "PSFT_20110328114728073793";
  long bookId  = Long.parseLong(buyId  .replaceAll("PSFT_",""));
```

Error:

```
10:12:10,522 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20110328094108069414"
10:12:10,522 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
10:12:10,522 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:415)
10:12:10,522 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:461)
10:12:10,522 ERROR [STDERR]     at unilog.com.user.ejb.userDAOORCL.checkCWSUserReg(userDAOORCL.java:363)
10:12:10,522 ERROR [STDERR]     at unilog.com.user.ejb.userEJBBean.checkCWSUserReg(userEJBBean.java:141)
10:12:10,522 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
10:12:10,523 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
10:12:10,523 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
10:12:10,523 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
10:12:10,523 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.invocation.Invocation.performCall(Invocation.java:359)
10:12:10,523 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb.StatelessSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatelessSessionContainer.java:237)
10:12:10,523 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:158)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use [BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

For example:

```
BigInteger bi;

String buyId  = "PSFT_20110328114728073793";
bi  = new BigInteger(buyId.replaceAll("PSFT_",""));
```

Add try-catch block too, with NumberFormatException

Answer (score 6):

The largest allowed `long` is

```
  9223372036854775807L
```

and your value is:

```
  20110328094108069414L
```

You can't use a `long` for this.  You could use `BigInteger` instead, but given the use-case, I think that `String` would be the most appropriate type.  (I can't imagine you *needing* to do integer arithmetic on book ids, and if you need to do numeric comparison, you could easily implement a custom Comparator to do that on decimal strings.)

Answer (score 1):

20110328094108069414 is out of the range of long.

Answer (score 0):

What about using something suiting for storing timestamps more than just a long? Date class? or JodaTime? Probably this post also will be helpful: Joda time : [How to convert String to LocalDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721614/joda-time-how-to-convert-string-to-localdate)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the label PSFT_20110328114728073793 was ever intended to be used arithmetically. It seems to be a combination of type, date and ID. As others have pointed out  20110328114728073793 won't fit in a long. Maybe splitting the string into its original parts would make more sense for your use case ?

Answer (score 0):

The number is out of Long range. Use BigInteger!