# How do I create a java.time.LocalDate from a date string using the "d. LLLL YYYY" pattern?

Tags: java, parsing, date, java-8

I'm trying to create a LocalDate object:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(
    "1. juli 2014", 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d. LLLL YYYY", new Locale("nb", "NO"));
```

But I get an exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '1. juli 2014' could not be parsed: 
    Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: 
    {WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[MONDAY,4]]=2014, MonthOfYear=7, DayOfMonth=1},
    ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1919)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1854)
at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
```

The exception seems to indicate that the correct data is in there ("juli" is Norwegian and is month number 7).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joda time : How to convert String to LocalDate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721614/joda-time-how-to-convert-string-to-localdate)

Comment: @MarceloBezerra Nope, that's for Joda time, not Java 8 time

Comment: I think you might have found a bug in jdk 8, congratulations, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874374/what-is-the-motivation-for-two-different-week-based-year-definitions-in-jsr-310

Comment: @NimChimpsky Horray! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I found the solution, even though [this probably is a Java 8 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874374/what-is-the-motivation-for-two-different-week-based-year-definitions-in-jsr-310), as @NimChimpsky commented on.

By using `"d. LLLL yyyy"` (with year-of-era) instead of `"d. LLLL YYYY"` (with week-based-year), the parsing works as intended.

Comment: Fun fact: joda-time uses `YYYY` as year-of-era, while java-time uses `yyyy`