# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-2-2' could not be parsed at index 5

Tags: java, date

I am trying to make an instance of `LocalDate` from `import java.time.LocalDate;`
and i follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721614/joda-time-how-to-convert-string-to-localdate)

and here is my code:

```
     LocalDate sd=  LocalDate.parse("2016-2-2");
```

and i faced with the error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-2-2' could not be parsed at index 5
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
```

---

In another try to make an instance of `LocalDate`, i tried

```
LocalDate ed=  new LocalDate("2016-2-4");
```

but it again complains:

```
The constructor LocalDate(String) is undefined
```

Comment: The link you have provided is regarding `org.joda.time.LocalDate` not `java.time.LocalDate`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a formatter to parse single character day/month fields for `java.time.LocalDate`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-d");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2016-2-2", formatter);
```

Answer (score -7):

LocalDate simply can't parse that string. Use SimpleDateFormat instead: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: LocalDate *can* parse that string, and recommending to use an obsolete class is not very helpful.