# Java 6 alternatives for LocalDate and DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, java-6, date-parsing

In a Java 8 project, I can parse the date this way:

```
LocalDate.parse(
    newDateString, 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(expectedDateFormat) 
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(expectedDBDateFormat)
);
```

My problem is that I have a Java 6 project, and `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` are not defined for Java 6.

How can I parse the date in my Java 6 project?

Comment: Just use an external library for example [joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Comment: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Agreed with @YCF_L. Use http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ to get trhead-safe library to work with dates for Java 6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert java.util.Date to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683728/convert-java-util-date-to-string)

Comment: also related [Change date format in a Java string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string) and if you like to use Joda [Joda time : How to convert String to LocalDate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721614/joda-time-how-to-convert-string-to-localdate)

Comment: When we have the ThreeTen Backport for Java 6 and 7, I got no idea why anybody is mentioning old and outdated options like Joda-Time or worse, `Date` and the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`. Fortunately a couple of the answers have got it right.

Comment: You generally shouldn’t format your date into a string for your database. It’s better to transfer a date object to your prepared statement or JPA implementation, and it will insert the date value into your `date` datatype column. Normally you could transfer the `LocalDate` directly. Unfortunately with Java 6 you need to give it a `java.sql.Date`, but the conversion is straightforward: `DateTimeUtils.toSqlDate(yourLocalDate)`.

Comment: @OleV.V. I agree with you and with Andrea its better to use ThreeTen-Backport, also for user880386 just accept the answer of Adreas its better then me, there is no shame to say the truth ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to use [Joda time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), you can just make some changes in your code, your code should like like this :

```
LocalDate.parse(
     newDateString, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(expectedDateFormat)
).toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern(expectedDBDateFormat));
```

---

### The imports

The imports should be :

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
```

Instead of :

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

---

### Method names

If you note there are a small changes :

```
In Java 8 Time                            In Joda Time 
ofPattern(String pattern)           =>    forPattern(String pattern)   
format(DateTimeFormatter format)    =>    toString(DateTimeFormat format)
```

Comment: Ok. I wii try it.
it will also work with java7?Thanks a lot

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, the pattern syntax needs to be changed in some cases, too.

Comment: Since Joda-Time recommends *"from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310)"*, wouldn't it be better for new Java 6/7 projects to use the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) instead? The methods and patterns would remain the same. Anyway, that's what [I recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50353937/5221149).

Answer (score 11):

There are 3 main choices:

- Use [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) ***(Recommended)***
  Advantage: Mostly same API as Java 8 Time API (JSR-310). Migration to Java 8 is very easy.
  Disadvantage: Package names are different, and it is not a full implementation of JSR-310.

  ```
  import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;
  import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;

  LocalDate.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(inputFormat))
           .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outputFormat));
  ```
- Use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
  Advantage: Will work with any Java version.
  Disadvantage: Deprecated, in favor of Java 8 Time API (JSR-310).

  ```
  import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
  import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;

  LocalDate.parse(input, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(inputFormat))
           .toString(DateTimeFormat.forPattern(outputFormat));
  ```
- Use Java 6 [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
  Advantage: Will work for all future Java versions. No 3rd-party library.
  Disadvantage: The API is flawed, which is why Java 8 Time API (JSR-310) was created.

  ```
  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

  new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat).format(
      new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat).parse(input));
  ```

For comparison, your Java 8 code is:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

LocalDate.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(inputFormat))
         .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outputFormat));
```

Comment: this is nice @Andreas +1

Comment: I suggest reversing the order of your billets, putting recommended route at the top.

Comment: Agree. The bullit should be recomended top first

Answer (score 4):

The `java.time`-API has a [backport](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) operating for Java 6 or 7. So I think this is the simplest approach with as few changes as possible.

Other answers have also advocated Joda-Time, but the main disadvantage is a change of format pattern syntax so more than just changing import statements or the replacement of constructors versus factory methods is necessary.

Finally (for completeness), there is also my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) (v3.x for Java 6) which contains an alternative parse/format-engine based on the class `ChronoFormatter` (and the equivalent `PlainDate` instead of `LocalDate`).

Answer (score -1):

In vanilla Java 6 you can use the **Date** type and **SimpleDateFormat** class to parse string/format string represented dates.

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedDateFormat);
Date date = parser.parse(input);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(expectedDBDateFormat);
String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
```

As mentioned in other answers, both classes have their issues hence they have been superseeded by the Date/Time API since Java 8. Prefer one of those options or bettery yet avoid storing string formatted dates in the database.

Comment: Hi butchyyyy and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Code-only answers are generally discouraged on Stack Overflow, which is probably why someone down-voted your answer.  Could you add an English explanation of how/why your code solves the problem?  Thanks!